# Google places returns no administrative_area_level_1 (region)

Tags: javascript, google-places-api

I am using Google places to get French addresses (with javascript).
The address `40 Boulevard de Scarpone, 54000 Nancy, France` does not return any `administrative_area_level_1` (region).
However, it should return `Lorraine` or `Alsace-Champagne-Ardenne-Lorraine`.

What is weird is that we do have the (correct) data for `administrative_area_level_2` (department). And with the department one can find the region...

Is it a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not every location will return all the valid options, especially in rural areas. It's not unique to this one location. Could you have any fallback options so that if there's no level_1 you could use level_2 or locality?

Comment: Nancy is not rural... 100,000 inhabitants! In the retrieved data, there is the level_2 information (department). For one department there is a unique region (level_1). So google should be able to find this information!

Comment: It's not a prefect system so there's always going to be data missing, even in larger urban centers. Unless you're able to get google maps to add level_1 data or use a slightly different address there's not much that can be done. It'd be good to have fallback options for addresses that won't have all the data you need...

Comment: `Unless you're able to get google maps to add level_1 data`... How to do that? The region field is currently mandatory in my application. Should I make it optional?

Comment: Not sure if it's even possible to be honest, I know google maps used to allow users to add data but it might just have been for places without any data. If you can't get the right region data (from level_1 or another field) for all your addresses leaving it optional is probably your only option.